# Emojis in .tsv file are breaking read.table() and adding rows

Tags: r, csv

When read.table encounters an emoji in text data, it inserts several EOL prematurely before continuing a new line beginning with data on the same line it was interrupted on.

Tried permutations of parameters on read.table, read.delim

```
myData <- read.table("myData.tsv", sep = '\t', encoding = "UTF-16", skipNul = TRUE, fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, skip = 3, quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Replicated using this dataset:

```
StartDate   Q15.5   Q16.5   gc  response_order
Start Date  Which of these statements best reflect how you feel about [Brand]? [Brand] is _____.    "In your own words, why do you feel that [Brand] is [QID32-ChoiceGroup-SelectedChoices]?"   gc  response_order
"{""ImportId"":""startDate"",""timeZone"":""America/Denver""}"  "{""ImportId"":""QID32""}"  "{""ImportId"":""QID33_TEXT""}" "{""ImportId"":""gc""}" "{""ImportId"":""response_order""}"
4/4/2019 9:39   Holding its ground  i dont really hear much about it but i would assume its holding its ground  1   reversed
4/4/2019 9:37   Probably on its way up  ‍‍    1   reversed
4/4/2019 9:29   Probably on its way up  Growing company 1   normal
4/4/2019 9:37   Holding its ground  "It is mostly geared towards the younger generation, which is good because it calls to new customers. On the other hand, the older generations are moving on to business that more geared towards us."  1   normal
4/4/2019 9:17   Probably on its way up  Its well used and good  1   reversed
4/4/2019 9:41   Probably on its way up  Its going good  1   normal
4/4/2019 9:38   Definitely on its way up    reasons 1   normal
4/4/2019 9:38   Holding its ground  It's beginning to look less like a fly by night outfit and more like a responsible company  1   normal
4/4/2019 9:38   Holding its ground  "I feel that the company, while providing a useful service, is not constantly working to innovate and continue building upon the product to match the needs of the customer."   1   reversed
4/4/2019 9:37   Definitely on its way up    They are a trustworthy company that constantly stays in tune with the technology of today   1   normal
4/4/2019 9:48   Holding its ground  I still hear about it   1   normal
```

Resulting in:

```
"X....ImportId.....startDate.....timeZone.....America.Denver....","X....ImportId.....QID32....","X....ImportId.....QID33_TEXT....","X....ImportId.....gc....","X....ImportId.....response_order...."
"4/4/2019 9:39","Holding its ground","i dont really hear much about it but i would assume its holding its ground ",1,"reversed"
"4/4/2019 9:37","Probably on its way up","=ØhÜ<Øþß",NA,""
" <Ø>ß=ØÞ>Ø/Ý=ØhÜ<Øþß","","",NA,""
" <Ø>ß>Ø/Ý=ØÞ>Ø/Ý=ØÞ>Ø/Ý","1","reversed",NA,""
"4/4/2019 9:29","Probably on its way up","Growing company",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:37","Holding its ground","""It is mostly geared towards the younger generation, which is good because it calls to new customers. On the other hand, the older generations are moving on to business that more geared towards us.""",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:17","Probably on its way up","Its well used and good",1,"reversed"
"4/4/2019 9:41","Probably on its way up","Its going good",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:38","Definitely on its way up","reasons",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:38","Holding its ground","It's beginning to look less like a fly by night outfit and more like a responsible company",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:38","Holding its ground","""I feel that the company, while providing a useful service, is not constantly working to innovate and continue building upon the product to match the needs of the customer.""",1,"reversed"
"4/4/2019 9:37","Definitely on its way up","They are a trustworthy company that constantly stays in tune with the technology of today",1,"normal"
"4/4/2019 9:48","Holding its ground","I still hear about it ",1,"normal"
```

Comment: Unless you can supply us with a sample file that breaks like this, I doubt we can help. The sample you've posted in here could have been mashed in several ways in its journey into HTML.  If I cut and paste it from here your code works or me and I see the emojis. You should also list your Sys.info() and anything else relevant like operating system and langauge.

Comment: ```> Sys.info()
         sysname          release          version         nodename          machine            login             user   effective_user 
       "Windows"         "10 x64"    "build 17134"    "CMAND-T470S"         "x86-64" "Charles.Mander" "Charles.Mander" "Charles.Mander" 
```

Comment: File is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai2X13Oz2l7KnrlnULG0JTIUMknu1g @Spacedman